# How do you use prepare when asking for a list of id's

Tags: wpdb, sql

I'm looking to get a number of records back from the database given a list of numbers and was wondering how I would use $wpdb->prepare to do this (to take advantage of the sanitising vs SQL injection attacks that it gives me).

A wrong way of going about what I'd like to achieve is `$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (' . implode(',', $ids) .')` but this gives the chance of an SQL Injection attack (imagine one of the ids having the value "0); DROP TABLE wp_posts;").

NOTE: I'm not trying to select data from wp_postmeta, I'm just using it as example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$wpdb->prepare()` use the same syntax for formatting like php's `printf()`. SSo you will need something like `... WHERE post_id IN (%d,%d,%d) ...`

This will fit for three ids. But what if we got more or less than three ids? We will use the php tools to create the needed formatting string (assuming `$ids` is an array with the ids):

Count the IDs

```
count( $ids )
```

Create a string with a '%d,' for every ID in $ids

```
str_repeat( '%d,', count( $ids ) )
```

Now we have a string like `%d,%d,%d,`. There is one comma to much at the end. Let's remove it

```
$ids_format_string = rtrim( str_repeat( '%d,', count( $ids ) ), ',' );
```

And use this in this way `'... WHERE post_id IN (' . $ids_format_string . ') ...'`

Answer (score 1):

In your case you know what kind of data you expect, so I would *force* that type:

```
$ids = array_map( 'absint', $ids );
```

And then you can use these values without further preparation.